# How I Handle the time response in jQuery.Ajax (DataType: JSON)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have four funcion as this. Each one them  is working.

```
$.ajax({
         url: sectoresURL,
         context: document.body,
         timeout: 10000 // 1000 MS = 10 Seconds
       }).done(function(jsonSectores) {
           // Blablabla...
       });
```

but when I must display each one them on screen, the last funcion is showing first than the first function... (Yes, It's correct because It takes less time).

For example:

```
Get Http://... 200 ms
Get Http://... 150 ms
Get Http://... 100 ms
Get Http://... 50 ms
```

So, How to Handle it? I'd like to show on screem the first function, then, the second function, ..., etc.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's deferreds are essentially a type of promise. Take advantage of that fact.

You want all the ajax methods to execute as early as possible to introduce the least delay to the user:

```
var p1, p2, p3, p4;
p1 = $.ajax(...);
p2 = $.ajax(...);
p3 = $.ajax(...);
p4 = $.ajax(...);
```

But you also need their callbacks to wait until the previous ajax requests were also finished.

You can do this with [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
var p1Done, p2Done, p3Done, p4Done;
p1Done = p1.then(function (p1Resolution) {...});
p2Done = $.when(p1Done, p2).then(function (p1Resolution, p2Resolution) {...});
p3Done = $.when(p2Done, p3).then(function (p2Resolution, p3Resolution) {...});
p4Done = $.when(p3Done, p4).then(function (p3Resolution, p4Resolution) {...});
```

---

**A word of caution:**

If you structure your code this way, and any of the promises get rejected, be sure to handle the failure state appropriately. All it takes is a little network latency for a request to timeout and the entire promise chain to fail.

Comment: Hey dude, I've tried with your example but I without successful.

Comment: When the sequence enters in `p2Done = $.when(p1Done, p2).then(...);`. It always returns me `undefined`. So please... Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: @JavierMuñoz, jsfiddle?

Comment: you may want to use `$.when(p2, p1Done)` or double check the arguments that you're receiving in your `then` callbacks.

Comment: Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/jamunoz/myvmncj6/

Please, if you could check it.

Comment: @JavierMuñoz, read [the `jQuery.when` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) more carefully. You need to include more parameters in your then callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `$.when()`.

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), when accepts a number of promises and returns a promise-like object.  The success callback passed to `.then()` will be called with the values of the promises passed to `.when()` when they have all been resolved.

And just for completeness, I say `$.when()` returns a *promise-like* object because the success handler takes an argument for every promise provided to `$.when()`.  Real promises resolve with a single value.

Anyways, here's an example:

```
$.when(
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  context: document.body,
  timeout: 10000
 }),
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  context: document.body,
  timeout: 10000
 })
).then(
 function (first, second) {
  console.log("The first result is: " + first[0]);
  console.log("The second result is: " + second[0]);
 },
 function(e) {
  console.log("Something happened: " + e);
 }
);
```

This approach is preferred over chaining as the AJAX requests will run in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Create dependent ajax call as per sequence you want like

```
$.ajax({
        url: sectoresURL, //First Call
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data){
            $.ajax({
                url: "example/",// Second call
                data: 'page='+a,
                success: function(data){
                      //Call your 3rd function if you want and so on
               });
});
```

Comment: Why negative vote? Please explain so that I can improve

Comment: A couple improvements, #1 nested callbacks introduces [unnecessary arrow code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). #2 this format will mean that each ajax request occurs successively meaning the longest possible wait for the user.